# Why javascript event handler is performing differently in different browser?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I am new to javascript and I am curious about a piece of code and why it is behaving differently in different browsers. This is the piece of code that I have.

```js
function waitThreeSeconds() {
    var ms = 3000 + new Date().getTime();
    while(new Date() < ms) {}
    console.log('Finished function!')
}

function clickHandler() {
    console.log('Clicked event!')
}

document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)

waitThreeSeconds();
console.log('Finished execution!')
```

As of now, I know that javascript is synchronous and single-threaded. Whenever some sort of events occur javascript puts it in the event queue and waits for the execution stack to be empty. Once the execution stack is empty then it looks into the event queue and processes the events one after another. Even after finishing all the event processing javascript still looks in the event queue for further events to appear.

Keeping this in mind, if I run this code and **don't click** in the window during the three seconds of delay, the output is

```
Finished function!
Finished execution!
```

and after the code executed if I clicked in the window, depending on the number of times I clicked the output becomes,

```
Finished function!
Finished execution!
Clicked event!
Clicked event!
...
...
```

Now, this is what I was expecting.

How ever, if I run the code and click in the window during the three seconds of delay, depending on the number of times I clicked the output that I expect is

```
Finished function!
Finished execution!
Clicked event!
Clicked event!
...
...
```

and it is happing for Google Chrome. However, if I do the same thing for Brave browser the output becomes

```
Finished function!
Finished execution!
```

Though I have clicked the window the output seems to look like I never clicked the window which is confusing for me.

However, after completion of execution, the code works the same way as it should be in both the browsers.

Can anybody help me to understand this behavior?

Comment: Must be how the browser quantifies `new Date()` vs `new Date().getTime()`, but really why not use `function wait(seconds, func){ setTimeout(func, seconds*1000); } wait(3, ()=>{ console.log('three seconds have passed'); });`

Comment: @StackSlave `setTimeout` is not something that I want. I just want to mimic a function that takes a good amount of time for computation. `setTimeout` also uses event queue the same as a `click` event, which is different from my use case. Anyways, restarting my system solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to run the code in different browser `Chrome` and `Brave`，the result looks same.

#### Brave

version: 1.11.104 Chromium: 84.0.4147.105

#### Chrome

version: 84.0.4147.105

[image]
[image]

Comment: Restarting the system solved the issue. Anyways, thanks!